# Match string with database in django/python

Tags: python, django, django-views

A user will come on website and fill the registration form. Registration form has a question displayed below Which subjects you want to study?

Answer by user - I want to study Environmental Studies.

```
 sentence="I want to study Environmental Studies"
```

I have 2 database displayed below. Now the answer by the user should match with the one database table with maximum accuracy , The database table matching with maximum accuracy should get selected . I am not able to match with accuracy.

```
Class_A

   id                     subject
    1                     Environmental Studies
    2                     Physical education


Class_B

   Id                     subject
    1                     Social Science
    2                     Computer Management
    3                     Hindi
```

views.py

```
def submission(request):
    obj = Registration.objects.latest('id')
    obj1 = Registration.objects.filter(name__contains=obj1)
    for a in obj1:
        sentence= a.subject
        word = sentence.split()
        class_a=class_A.objects.all()
        class_b=class_B.objects.all()

        if Class_a.filter(subject__in=word).exists():
            return render(request,'data/submission.html',{'Class':'Your Are in Class A'})
        elif Class_b.filter(subject__in=word).exists():
            return render(request, 'data/submission.html', {'Class': 'You are in Class B'})
```

The system is working fine with one word subject added in a database Table Like Hindi , English ("I want to study Hindi."). But when 2 words or 3 words Subject is added in a database table like Physical education or Environmental Studies. Then the system doesnt work . Like if the user Fills the registration form by writing " I want to study Environmental Studies." , Then it doesnt matches because of 2 words subject .

Comment: You probably want to use [`contains`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#contains) in your queryset

Comment: Why would you create a form that expects the user to type in a sentence, rather than selecting from a list?